# How to pass value and functions from one component to another in function components in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass the value written in input field to app component and show it in h1 tag

You can refer to this sandbox I have attached. I have already tried passing function as prop but it doesn't help.

[view CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-field-n4981?file=/src/App.js)

Also, I really struggle and get confused when to pass value or when to pass function can someone explain me that as well.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a relevant code example ***in the question***? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You've a typo in `App`, `<Form onChange={handleChange} />` should be `<Form handleChange={handleChange} />` as `handleChange` is the name of the prop in `Form`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Form` component, replace `onChange={props.handleChange}` with `onChange={props.onChange}` since the prop you are passing into `Form` is called `onChange` not `handleChange`.

[image: Edit bold-boyd-srjrf]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any data as a `props` in react component.
[Components and props in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Example :

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome name="Sara" />
      <Welcome name="Cahal" />
      <Welcome name="Edite" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In your component It's typo mistake.

Use `props.onChange` insted of `props.handleChange`